# How does Facebook show notifications in your login page even though you are logged out?

Tags: facebook, reactjs, notifications

Facebook just rolled out their new login feature, where the user can just click on the profile picture in the login page and type the password to login. It is clearly an improvement in usability and accessibility. But, I am very much interested in knowing about it's technical approach.

The notifications appear on to the side of the profile pic in login page.How do they push notifications to your login page even though the user is not logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're worried about technical details of how this feature would work, it's hard to tell what exactly is happening under the hood. But, considering the bigger picture, you aren't technically logged out of Facebook when you see the page where you need to click on your profile picture.

It's just an extra layer of security when your session ends, you come back and enter your password to access your account once again. You are ***logged-in*** technically, but you can't access your data without going through the re-verification process.